# Perl regex dotall problems

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I'm trying to fetch certain values from a file that I've created with a system command. The file is in order and the regex is working up until I reach a "newline". I've tried to get it to grab the other value in multiple ways, but I can't seem to figure it out. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code

```
sub servicechoise2 {

    my $sys_com = "Servicestatus.txt";

    print "type status you would like to see status of: ";
    my $service = <>;
    chomp $service;

    system( "systemctl status $service > $sys_com" );

    open( my $fh2, "<", $sys_com );

    my @services;

    while ( my $line = <$fh2> ) {

        if ( $line =~ /([a-z]+.service)\s-.*(running|dead)/s ) {

            my %hash2 = (
                "servicename"   => $1,
                "servicestatus" => $2
            );

            push( @services, \%hash2 );
        }
    }

    return \@services;
}
```

and here is the file I'm parsing

```
sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled)    Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-08-21 18:20:06 CEST; 1h 32min ago  Main PID: 1297 (sshd)    CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─1297 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Aug 21 18:20:06 Thomas-PC systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon. Aug 21 18:20:07 Thomas-PC sshd[1297]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port
22. Aug 21 18:20:07 Thomas-PC sshd[1297]: Server listening on :: port 22.

cups.service - CUPS Printing Service    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled)    Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-08-21 18:20:33 CEST; 1h 32min ago  Main PID: 3657 (cupsd)    CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           └─3657 /usr/sbin/cupsd -f

Aug 21 18:20:33 Thomas-PC systemd[1]: Started CUPS Printing Service.

ntpd.service - Network Time Service    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled)    Active: inactive (dead)


named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled)    Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-08-21 18:20:10 CEST; 1h 32min ago   Process: 2477 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 1302 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 2502 (named)    CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
           └─2502 /usr/sbin/named -u named

Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.biz/A/IN': 2001:503:7bbb:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff7e#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.biz/AAAA/IN': 2001:503:7bbb:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ff7e#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.biz/A/IN': 2001:500:3682::12#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.biz/AAAA/IN': 2001:500:3682::12#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'ns2.isc.ultradns.net/A/IN': 2001:502:4612::e8#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.com/AAAA/IN': 2001:502:f3ff::e8#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.com/AAAA/IN': 2610:a1:1016::e8#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.co.uk/AAAA/IN': 2610:a1:1017::e8#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.co.uk/A/IN': 2610:a1:1017::e8#53 Aug 21 19:20:11 Thomas-PC named[2502]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.biz/A/IN': 2610:a1:1015::e8#53

postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled)    Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-08-21 18:20:10 CEST; 1h 32min ago   Process: 1335 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Process: 1328 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 1298 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 2531 (master)    CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─2531 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─2534 pickup -l -t unix -u
           └─2535 qmgr -l -t unix -u

Aug 21 18:20:06 Thomas-PC systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent... Aug 21 18:20:09 Thomas-PC postfix/postfix-script[2510]: warning: group or other writable: /etc/postfix/./main.cf Aug 21 18:20:10 Thomas-PC postfix/postfix-script[2529]: starting the Postfix mail system Aug 21 18:20:10 Thomas-PC postfix/master[2531]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix Aug 21 18:20:10 Thomas-PC systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent. Aug 21 18:23:08 Thomas-PC postfix/smtpd[4293]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1] Aug 21 18:23:08 Thomas-PC postfix/smtpd[4293]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <a14thona@localhost>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<admin@localhost> to=<a14thona@localhost> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost.localdomain> Aug 21 18:23:08 Thomas-PC postfix/smtpd[4293]: lost connection after RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1] Aug 21 18:23:08 Thomas-PC postfix/smtpd[4293]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

the subroutine returns this array of hashes

```
[
  { servicename => "sshd.service", servicestatus => "running" },
  { servicename => "cups.service", servicestatus => "running" },
  { servicename => "ntpd.service", servicestatus => "dead" },
  { servicename => "named.service", servicestatus => "running" },
  { servicename => "postfix.service", servicestatus => "running" },
]
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?

Comment: Using the `s` modifier on the regex for `$line` does not make much sense when you read line by line..

Comment: `[a-z]+.service` should probably be `[a-z]+\.service`.

Comment: I've added to your question a dump of the array returned by your subroutine. It looks fine to me. I don't understand *"the regex is working up until I reach a "newline""* and can't see what you mean by *the other value*. Please explain?

Comment: When I run the script I get an empty var in return, it ends at the new line after "OpenSSH server daemon"! Did you just run my script and it worked? By other value I'm refering to "running" and "dead". Can only get it to work with the first value which is the service name it self.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to read the answer into a var, and then process the tokens using split ( it seems there are empty lines between tokens) something like:

open(F,"<",file) || die "...";
{ local $/; $in=; } # slurp file

foreach $line ( split(/\n\n/,$in) ) 
{
  if ( $line =~ /([a-z]+.service)\s-.*(running|dead)/s ) {
  ......
}